# Is a question "is this possible" too broad?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few questions like [this one](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13258/use-arduino-to-read-data-from-ibeacon) which seem so broad as to be meaningless.

> My requirement is to read data from ibeacons near me using Arduino. Is it possible?

Well, most things are possible, with enough effort. Maybe not video editing on a Duemilanove, but you get the idea.

I voted to close that one because it was a virtual duplicate of [another post by the same fellow](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/reading-ibeacon-data-using-hc-05-bluetooth-module) but in any case isn't this question a bit hard to answer?

I personally try to be helpful if I can, but questions like that seem to suggest that the OP has not done any research at all, and basically wants code written. In the second thread I linked he said:

> My requirement is to read data transmitted from iBeacon, is it possible using HC-05 or I have to shift to HM-10?
>
> Please help.

Am I being too harsh? Or do we need to encourage people to try a bit harder with their questions?

Comment: The referenced question is crystal clear to anyone who knows the first thing about the technologies in question.  Those who don't understand it probably aren't in a position to write useful answers anyway.  Compatibility of radio modems is relatively binary - they either work together or they don't with little room between. The first referenced device (HC-05) is incompatible no matter what someone does, while the second (HM-10) contains one of the two most widely used chips for that purpose, meaning that it merely comes down to the question of what firmware has been loaded into that chip.

Comment: "Well, most things are possible, with enough effort. Maybe not video editing on a Duemilanove..." Challenge accepted!